# Get Data from Dictionary to List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have these classes in my C# project

```
public class Category
        {
            [Key]
            public int CategoryId { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
        }

public class Subcategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
    }

public class Offer
    {
        [Key]
        public int OfferId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

I have this class in my MVC Project

```
public class OfferViewModel
    {
        public int OfferId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<SubCategoryViewModel>> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```

An Offer can contain multiple Subcategories. So I want to add into my DB, the offer and the Subcategories.

```
public static bool GetModel(int UserId, OfferViewModel offerViewModel)
        {
            Offer offer = new Offer();
            offer.UserId = UserId;
            offer.Title = offerViewModel.Title;
for(int i=0;i<offerViewModel.Categories.Keys.Count;i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < offerViewModel.Categories[offerViewModel.Categories.Keys.ElementAt(i)].Count; j++)
                { 
                    offer.Subcategory.Add(
                        new Subcategory{
                            SubCategoryId = offerViewModel.Categories[offerViewModel.Categories.Keys.ElementAt(i)][j].Id
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
}
```

I am getting NULL to second FOR

Comment: I suppose you mean "Why the second for is getting me null?" as your question. Your question does not look like a question.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is my first Post here. I am new to MVC 4. Thanks

Comment: You are probably not properly binding to your dictionary. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4358279/1026459

Comment: I am binding well, but I don't know to get the values.

Comment: Are you posting these data back from a View?

Comment: Yes. I am posting from View

Comment: The problem was that this list was null offer.Subcategory and I couldn't add items to it.